# What does "m'a" mean?

Tags: contractions

How does "m'a" translate to English? Could this be a contraction of me + a (avoir)?

Comment: Without getting into the quality of your question, I'd suggest that it is extremely similar to one that has been asked and nicely answered very recently right [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13458/why-is-there-an-a-here).

Answer (score 1):

You can translate it that way: "Il m'a fait" can be read as: "Il **a** fait á **m**oi". It is only that it sounds better to the hear to say: Il m'a fait.

Comment: I'll m'a vu(e) - lit. "he saw me", il m'a fait mal - lit. "he hurt me"